# Does Eclipse have a shortcut to split a line and introduce a variable?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

During typing in code, I often have code lines that become long:

```
String result = new MyObject(foo, bar).getBaz().getFoo(new Config(new File(f))).get(key).get(0);
```

I frequently break up such a line manually, making two of them:

```
Foo foo = new MyObject(foo, bar).getBaz().getFoo(new Config(new File(f)));
String result = foo.get(key).get(0);
```

This means positioning the cursor after `new File(f)))`, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then select the `String result =` part, cut and paste it from the first to the second line, create a new variable named like the getter, type it in at the beginning of the second line and at the beginning of the first line, the latter as an assignment, with declaration. A lot of manual typework if you do it often enaugh.

I wonder again and again if there is a help, like a keyboard short cut, which does this for me: I position the cursor after `new File(f)))`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd> and the result is the two lines. A second one I wonder if it exists is if I would position the cursor on `Config` at the first line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd> and it would form these lines:

```
Config config = new Config(new File(f));
String result = new MyObject(foo, bar).getBaz().getFoo(config).get(key).get(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it. Long version:

- Position the cursor as described in the question, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. A dialog will appear to configure the variable name, whether all occurrences shall be replaced or the variable should be declared final. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as you aggree to the settings.

Short version:

- Position the cursor as described in the question, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and the *quick fix* menu will appear (even if there is nothing marked red or yellow). Select *Extract to local variable* (or one of the related options, as you need) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For the second example to work, the cursor must be positioned either after the expression you want to cut out

```
….getBaz().getFoo(new Config(new File(f))<CURSOR HERE>).get(key).get(0);
```

or on the `new` keyword.